# Why can't I transfer data from my tablet with OTG support to my phone with USB?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, usb, tablet, file-transfer, usb-host-mode

### Problem

I want to copy music from my tablet to my phone with USB.

My tablet can't see the phone when connected which is somewhat strange because the phone sees that it is connected [and the tablet has OTG support.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-host-mode) Therefore I can't select the phone from 'Explorer', so I can't copy the files.

I can connect the phone to a laptop with Ubuntu 10.10 or Windows 7 pro without any trouble so the problem shouldn't be on the phone's side. And the phone can't see an USB stick directly, so even that won't work as file transfer.

### Tablet:

Wayteq xTab-100is with Android 4.0.3 and USB 2.0 OTG without Bluetooth

### Phone:

Nokia 2700 classic micro USB 2.0

Comment: your phone may want to start charging. It's possible that your tab cannot supply the power and caps the connection half way. Have a look at logcat output and search for usb power related lines. there are apps in the market to view logcat. If this is the case: you can do very little to fix it

Answer (score 1):

*At least one of the USB devices would need support for [host-mode USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usb-host-mode) - which is a hardware feature and therefore can't be upgraded via software - and the other needs to report as mass storage USB device.*

Since your tablet has OTG (=host-mode USB) support it may be a simply compatibility issue. Bluetooth may be an option, but it's slow.

Answer (score 0):

What about transferring the data from your tablet to your computer and then from your computer to your phone?

Besides that, I think your phone is too old to be recognized as a disk drive on your tablet anyway. Some tablets can read data via USB from sticks/phones, but I think this does not support phones like yours.